# Pandas. Сортировка строк по двум условиям

Tags: pandas

Хотел бы вывести таблицу чтобы данные удовлетворяли двум условиям. Строки в который в Столбце `"СчетДт" == 10,01`, и Столбец `"СубконтоКт1"==71,01`. Прописываю первое условие и все отображает ок. Добавляю второе и выводит ошибку.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Хотел чтобы отображалось как на втором рисунке, только по двум условиям, а не одному.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
df = pd.read_csv("333.csv", sep=';', header=0, index_col="СубконтоДт1", decimal=',') #загружаю файл
df = df[(df['СчетДт'] == '10.01')]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите на свой вопрос и ответьте на мой: глядя на все это вам хоть что-то понятно, вам хочется помочь автору этого вопроса?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не фото, а **текст** программы, чтобы возможно было копировать через буфер для тех, которые вам хотят помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df[(df['СчетДт'] == '10.01') & (df["СубконтоКт1"] == 71.01)]
```

Условия должно связать оператором и для всякого столбца применить имя таблицы.

В отличие от Питоновского `and` для применения к 2 скаляром, для векторов (столбцов) надо использовать оператор `&` и скобки.

Comment: Все отлично! Спасибо огромное!!!